# sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.format give wrong date

Tags: sapui5

For one Client, and only when switch the browser to english,  the following code:

```
convertTimeToDate: function(dateobj) {


            if ((dateobj == undefined) || (dateobj == null)) {
                return "";
            }


            var dateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({
                pattern: "dd. MMM YYYY"
            });

            var dateFormatted = dateFormat.format(dateobj);

           return dateFormatted;
},
```

returns when inputing the highdate '9999-12-31' the datestring '31. Dec 10000' what could be the problem? It is reproducible only on the maschine of this one person, but for her it happens ALWAYS.

Comment: if you share the before and after screenshot it will be helpful to understand better..

Comment: You can only see the problem in the debugger, the screenshot from the Field ist just a normal Datepicker that shows, normally '31. Dec 9999' but for the one Client the same date is formated to to '31. Dec 10000' the Input is always the Date 9999-12-31

Comment: accept an answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was plagued by the same 10k date. My pattern was `{pattern: 'MMMM Y'}`. Changing it to `{pattern: 'MMMM yyyy'}` solved the problem. I cannot find any documents on the difference between 'Y' and 'y' though.

Comment: Capitalized Y is for year in “Week of Year” based calendars, as stated in [Unicode formatting rules](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table). In these cases starting (or ending) week of the year can include days of a different year, so beware of YYYY, unless you know exactly when to use it.

Comment: my Problem was exactly this, the format was dd-MM-YYYY, changed it to yyyy now it works

Answer (score 3):

To avoid problems with timezones, especially in UI5 apps in HR, I decided to send/receive dates and times in ISO format as strings in my recent developments, it guarantees that a user in browser will see the same value as in the SAP back-end system.

To make sure you use these values both for input and output it is recommended to implement a [Custom Data Type](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/topic/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8).

Suppose you have an sap.m.DateRangeSelection which accepts JavaScript Date objects as **dateValue** and **secondDateValue**, and you want bind these properties to a model, where properties like **startDate** and **endDate** are date strings of yyyy-MM-dd pattern. 
In this case a sample custom data type can be like this:

```js
sap.ui.define([
 "sap/ui/model/SimpleType",
 "sap/ui/core/format/DateFormat"
], function(SimpleType, DateFormat) {
 "use strict";
 return SimpleType.extend("MyProject.model.ISODateType", {
  
    /**         
   * Converts JavaScript Date object to ISO date string    
   *         
   * @public         
   * @param {string} sISO the ISO value of the formatted property         
   * @returns {string}     
   */parseValue: function(oDate) {
   var oFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance({
    pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd"
   });
   return oFormat.format(oDate);
  },
  /**         
   * Produces JavaScript Date object from ISO date string    
   *         
   * @public         
   * @param {string} sISO the ISO value of the formatted property         
   * @returns {string}     
   */
  formatValue: function(sValue) {
   return new Date(sValue);
  },
  /**         
   * Validates the value to be parsed (should be ISO date string)        
   *         
   * @public         
   * no client side validation is required        
   * @returns {boolean} true         
   */
  validateValue: function(sValue) {
   var sPattern = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/;
   return sValue.match(sPattern);
  }
 });
});
```

And the binding in an XML View can look like this:

```xml
<DateRangeSelection
                width="30%"
                dateValue="{
                    path: '/startDate',
                    type: 'MyProject.model.ISODateType'
                }"
                secondDateValue="{
                    path: '/endDate',
                    type: 'MyProject.model.ISODateType'
                }"
                change="onDateIntervalChange"/>
```

Comment: wow thats a great idea. could you provide some code insights in your answer for custom data type? In the past I thought sending strings from the backend always generates overhead (converting when displaying in ui5, converting when sending to the backend for an update and so on)... would be great and also great for the community!

Answer (score 1):

just an idea: the user did something (whatever) in his browser and timezone is somehow different for him/her. did you try passing a fixed timezone during fomatting? it looks like some seconds are added .. maybe some converting offset or whatever.

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat/methods/sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance
@since 1.34.0 contains pattern symbols (e.g. "yMMMd" or "Hms") which will be converted into the pattern **in the used locale**, which matches the wanted symbols best. The symbols must be in canonical order, that is: Era (G), Year (y/Y), Quarter (q/Q), Month (M/L), Week (w/W), Day-Of-Week (E/e/c), Day (d/D), Hour (h/H/k/K/j/J), Minute (m), Second (s), Timezone (z/Z/v/V/O/X/x) See http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#availableFormats_appendItems

something like: https://gist.github.com/bvanzyl/b3b64306a7363f0b3e043608b48d8326

```
formatDateStr: function(data){
             if(data === null || data === undefined){
                    return data;
             }else{
                    var oDate = new Date(data);
                    var iLocalTime = oDate.getTime();
                    // Berlin timezone = UTC+1 = 1hr = 60min ahead 
                    // 60min * 60000 for time in milliseconds
                    var iBerlinOffset = 60 * 60000;
                    var iLocalOffset = oDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
                    var iBerlinTime = iLocalTime + iLocalOffset + iBerlinOffset;
                    oDate.setTime(iBerlinTime);
                    var dateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({pattern : "MMM, dd YYYY" });  
                    var dateFormatted = dateFormat.format(oDate);
                    return  dateFormatted;
             }
       }
   };
```